# Initialising a project as Git repository and using that as the master for multiple users

Tags: git

I'm completing a course assignment and it asks for a project directory to be turned into a local repository:

so inside '/home/Dev/project1':

```
$ git init
```

It's now a repository, but what I've done so multiple local users can push and pull changes is then clone this repo to a new *bare* repo

```
$ git clone —bare /home/Dev/project1 /home/Dev/project1_central
```

So now when a user logs in they can clone the bare repo

```
$git clone /home/Dev/project1_central /home/JohnSmith/project1
```

Make edits and changes and push back to the bare repo for others to pull the changes from.

My issue is that my assignment specifically states `/home/Dev/project1` is the master and push/pulls are made to that repo. So I feel like if I clone it to a bare repo I am not following the criteria, However when ever I try and push a change to a non-bare repo I get errors.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by _"is the master"_?

Comment: Thats the term that was used, I'd say `/home/Dev/project1` should be the central repository for multiple users to initially clone from, and then push changes back to.

Comment: The assignment sounds like it doesn't understand how git works. There's no such thing as a "master repo". Only remotes. You can act like one repo is a master by having all other clones set it to be their remote.

Comment: Ok so say `/home/Dev/project1` is the project directory I want to act as a master or central repository. User John logins in and `git clone /home/Dev/project1 johnsrepo`, so John now has a clone of the repo on his system, how does John set `/home/Dev/project1` as the remote?

Comment: If they clone it from the “central” repo then it’s already set up as the remote.

Comment: Ok, then they make some changes and want to push the changes back to the original repo, `$ git push`, and  `$ git push origin master`, give me an error saying things aren't going to match up right and I need to edit come configuration files.

Comment: Can you add those commands and their outputs to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ok, then they make some changes and want to push the changes back to the original repo,
>   `$ git push`, and `$ git push origin master`, give me an error saying things aren't going to match up right and I need to edit come configuration files.

If the remote repo `/home/Dev/project1` has been setup as a bare repo, there won't be any error message: a `git push -u origin master` will update the repote (`/home/Dev/project1`) `master` branch.

> I can get everything working fine by cloning the repo to a bare repo and going from there, but it seems the assignment question asks us to work directly from the repo with all the files

Then:

- make a regular repo in `/home/Dev/project1`
- add bare/ to its `.gitignore` file
- clone it in a bare subfolder

  ```
  git clone --bare . bare
  git remote add origin bare
  ```
- ask your colleagues to clone your `/home/Dev/project1` repo, *but add:

  ```
  git config set-url --push origin `/home/Dev/project1/bare`
  ```
- add a post-receive hook `/home/Dev/project1/bare/hooks/post-receive` which will

  ```
  unset GIT_DIR
  cd ..
  git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git fetch --tags
  ```

Comment: It's not bare. I can get everything working fine by cloning the repo to a bare repo and going from there, but it seems the assignment question asks us to work directly from the repo with all the files. But maybe I'm taking the wording too literally.

Comment: @AriVictor OK. I have edited the answer to comply with *all* your assignment parameters.